# how to give unique name to control in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in webform we never have to think about controls ID or name for unique ness. everything webform handle automatically. so tell me when we assign name to html control's ID then how can i provide unique name ? please help me with small code snippet

just see it

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field, ModelClass.MakeSelectListUtenti(Model.Destinations), new { id="Destinations"})
```

here we specify the controls id name as "Destination" but how can i specify name like "UniqueID_" + "Destination" ?

someone show me a way to do it like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field, ModelClass.MakeSelectListUtenti(Model.Destinations), new { id= @guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "Destinations"})
```

i like to know is there any other way around. i heard that something new technique has been introduce in mvc4. is it true....what is that?

if possible also show me various way to generate unique client side id in **mvc 3/4**.
thanks

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know,there is noway can do it on official way,so I suggest a jQuery way:

First set a custom attribute instead the id for dropdownlist like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Field, ModelClass.MakeSelectListUtenti(Model.Destinations), new { originalid="Destinations"})
```

And this can be put multi times,then write a script on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[originalid]").each(function () {
     var originalid = $(this).attr("originalid");
     $(this).attr("id", $("[originalid='" + originalid + "']").index($(this)) + "_" + originalid);
     });
})
```

And the same id will be init as "0_Destinations" "1_Destinations" etc.

Comment: is there nothing built-in class to do it in mvc 3/4 ? u have shown this to solve it by clientside script.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to VS to give you a code example, but I would do something similar to what you have been shown, but using integers.

I am assuming the ID's are an issue because you are creating dropdowns on the fly. Otherwise you would obviously just change the text.

If you are creating dropdowns on the fly from a list, you could put it within a for loop and use the current number as a pre-pend to your id. This would give a result like  id= @myInt + "_Destinations" -> '0_Destinations', '1_Destinations' etc. I have used this pattern many times. It makes for easy jQuery selection and is much tidier than Guid ids.

If you are not looping through a list, you could create a method that gives you a number and then pre-pend that in an Id.